# Python Ctypes function call from dll issue

Tags: python, c, dll, ctypes

I need to cal dll function with **python**.

The function is:

```
int cbGetConfigString(int InfoType, int BoardNum, int DevNum, int ConfigItem, char *ConfigVal, int* maxConfigLen)
```

### Arguments

**InfoType**

> The configuration information for each board is grouped into different
>   categories. This argument specifies which category you want. Always
>   set this argument to BOARDINFO.

**BoardNum**

> The number associated with the board when it was installed with
>   InstaCal or created with cbCreateDaqDevice(). BoardNum may be 0 to 99.

**DevNum**

> The purpose of the DevNum argument depends on the ConfigItem being
>   passed. It can serve as a point at which to start the read, an index
>   into the ConfigItem, or it can be ignored.

**ConfigItem**

> The type of information to read from the device. Set it to one of the
>   constants listed in the "ConfigItem argument values" section below.

**ConfigVal**

> Pointer to a user-allocated buffer where the configuration string is
>   copied.

**maxConfigLen**

> Pointer to the value holding the maximum number of bytes to be read
>   from the device into ConfigVal.

Please help me to understand what is wrong in my code:

```
import ctypes

mccdaq=ctypes.WinDLL("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Measurement Computing\\DAQ\\cbw32.dll")

Open=mccdaq.cbGetConfigString
Open.argtypes =[ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_int,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char),ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)]

INTP=ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)
num=ctypes.c_int(8)
addr=ctypes.addressof(num)
ptr=ctypes.cast(addr,INTP)

mem=ctypes.c_char()

print Open(2,0,0,363,ctypes.byref(mem),ctypes.byref(num))
print mem
print num
```

Output:

0 - no error

c_char('1') - should be 125E737

c_long(7) - looks correct number of characters..

Comment: I think you would normally use `create_string_buffer()` for `ConfigVal` / `mem` and use a normal `c_int` with `by_ref` for the int pointer.

Comment: As-is, cytpes.c_char_p() does not allocate any backing storage, it just gives you a pointer.  So chances are, your code will segfault when it makes that call.

Comment: Did you know `minimal required setting/data` of related DLL ?  C:\\Program Files(X86) with 64 bit DLL ? Can call `ctypes.WinDLL("cbw64.dll")` if you registered to OS ! Why ? Need some driver package for scanning/openning a port/device....

Comment: There's also a typo in the dll path (missing escaping backslash): `(x86)\Measurement`; should be `(x86)\\Measurement`

Comment: Ok, I updated my code..still got wrong char value but at least the function return 0 "no error" please assist

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the issue :)

```
import ctypes

mccdaq=ctypes.WinDLL("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Measurement Computing\\DAQ\\cbw32.dll")

Open=mccdaq.cbGetConfigString
Open.argtypes =[ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_int,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char*8),ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)]

num=ctypes.c_int(8)
mem=(ctypes.c_char*8)()

print Open(2,0,0,363,ctypes.byref(mem),ctypes.byref(num))
print mem.value
print num
```

now the output is:

0

125E737

c_long(7)

Comment: Your 5th parameter should just be `ctypes.c_char_p`.

Comment: Typically, use `mem = ctypes.create_string_buffer(8)` to create a writable buffer of the correct size.  You get the same result however.  Also no need for `ctypes.byref(mem)`.  `mem` is already the right type (char*).